# Evaluate Sympy boolean expression in python

Tags: python, sympy, sat

I am using Python and Sympy.

I have the following:

```
x,y,z = Symbols('x,y,z')
doc = {x : False, y : True, z: True}
rule = Or(x, And(y,z))
```

I am looking for a function in Sympy that will return `True` on `rule.eval(doc)`?

Edit:
Currently I am using `rule.subs` and `rule.xreplace` both are performing slowly with about 0.0003 seconds per call. This makes it impractical.

Comment: I am wondering why you can't do `rule.subs(doc)`?

Comment: Hi, you are right, I haven't mentioned it. This is what I have used, `rule.subs` and `rule.xreplace` they both work as expected, but have teribble performance. I have profiled my code and saw that each execution takes about 0.0003 of a second. I use these functions alot. I am looking for a more efficient way

Comment: And you must use sympy? If not then you could do: `import operator as op; rule = lambda x,y,z: op.or_(x, op.and_(y,z)); rule(False,True,True)`. Doesn't provide for the dict as it is but much faster.

Comment: Yes, there is some complex logic in the rest of the program that I have to use Sympy for. I can't seem to understand how such simple operation isn't implemented in Sympy. It has `evalf()` for numerical but not for boolean.

Answer (score 1):

A way to get better performance with minimal coding is to use `lambdify`:

```
X = tuple(doc.iterkeys())
f = lambdify(X, rule)
```

After this IPython gave me:

```
V = tuple(doc.itervalues())
%timeit f(*V)
The slowest run took 7.56 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 209 ns per loop
```

I am not sure how much the warning may impact the conclusion, but there is a clear improvement. On the same computer I had with the original code:

```
%timeit rule.xreplace(doc)
10000 loops, best of 3: 126 µs per loop
```

And subs was even slower.

Comment: `lambdify` will create a NumPy compatible function by default. In this case, something like `logical_or.reduce((x,logical_and.reduce((y,z))))` (look at `inspect.source(f)`). If you instead do `lambdify((x, y, z), rule, modules=[])`, it will produce a function that uses only Python, like `x or y and z`, which evaluates much faster (about as fast as is possible with pure Python).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using subs can you use direct evaluation?

```
>>> F = Lambda((x, y, z), Or(x, And(y, z)))
>>> F(0, 1, 1)
True
```

If not, could you create a toy class that will allow subs via the lambda form? This is not a class but it gives the idea:

```
>>> def sub(f, d):
...     F = Lambda(d.keys(), f)
...     return F(*[d[k] for k in d.keys()])
>>> sub(Or(x,And(y,z)),{x:0,y:1,z:1})
```

The class would create the Lambda form and have a subs method which would return the evaluated Lambda form.